# Jacobi Method and Gauss-Seidel Multiple Choice Convergence Answer Verification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra

The book gives the following problems.

> 1. A sufficient condition for the Jacobi method to converge for the linear system $Ax=b$ is ...
>    $a. \quad A-I$ is diagonally dominant
>    $b. \quad A$ is diagonally dominant
>    $c. \quad G$ is nonsingular where $G$ is the iteration matrix: $G=I-Q^{-1}A$.
>    $d.\quad $ The spectral radius of $G$ is less than $1$.
>    $e.\quad $ none of these.

My answer: $b.$ i.e. the condition that $A$ is diagonally dominant.

*Reasoning:* The book gives the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel Convergence Theorem:

> If $A$ is diagonally dominant, then the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods converge for any starting vector $x^{(0)}$. (Notice that this is a sufficient, but not a necessary condition.)

The next problem:

> 2. A sufficient condition for the Gauss-Seidel Method to work on the linear system $Ax=b$ is ...
>    $a. \quad A$ is diagonally dominant
>    $b. \quad A-I$ is diagonally dominant
>    $c.\quad $ The spectral radius of $A$ is less than $1$.
>    $d. \quad G$ is nonsingular.
>    $e.\quad $ none of these.

My answer: $a.$ that $A$ is diagonally dominant.

*Reasoning:* The book gives the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel Convergence Theorem, see above.

*Concerns:* I'm not sure if my answers are correct. It seems a bit too simple/straightforward.  I'm not sure if these are trick questions and I'm missing a key fact or idea.  Also the first question asks for a sufficient condition for Jacobi Method to converge, and the second question asks for a sufficient condition for Gauss-Seidel to work.

I'm not sure if there is a difference between converge and work.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For these methods convergence occurs *if and only if* the spectral radius of the iteration/error propagation matrix $G$ is strictly less then one:
$$\rho(G) \overset{!}<1.$$
Now, for a general matrix-splitting based method like Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel, you do the splitting $$A = Q - N$$ resulting in the iteration matrix $$G = I - Q^{-1} A = Q^{-1}N.$$
For the Jacobi method $Q_J = D, N_J = L+U$. So for question one, a certainly correct answer is **d.** Concerning diagonal-dominance, it is usually a matter of definition. [Jacobi converges guaranteed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence) for [strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) or [irreducible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreducibleMatrix.html) diag. dom. matrices $A$. Question is now, what your definition of diagonal-dominance is, i.e., whether **b.** is also correct or not.

This matter of definition determines actually also the outcome of the second question - it is either **b.** or **e.**.